# Custom issue posting to sonar sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I am working with sonarqube ,and i need to display some custom issues which reported by my SDK in sonarqube web console .
Is there any API available to post custom issues or give me any suggestion to do the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You would need to implement the rules in a custom plugin. You don't list a language, so I'll assume Java and point you at the documentation for implementing custom Java rules: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+Java

Comment: Thank you for reply , i am looking solution for java :)

Comment: i am trying to send some custom issues with my JAVA SDK .SDK is not the part of sonarqube and it is available only apart of my projects.Is above solution satisfy my requirement ,right ?